# Python re adding space when splitting

Tags: python, regex

I am using the following regex to split a phrase passed in as a string, into a list of words.

Because there might be other letters, I'm using the UTF flag. This works great in most cases:

```
phrase = 'hey look out'
word_list = re.split(r'[\W_]+', unicode(phrase, 'utf-8').lower(), flags=re.U)
word_list [u'hey', u'look', u'out']
```

But, if the phrase is a sentence that ends with a period like this, it will create a blank value in the list:

```
phrase = 'hey, my spacebar_is broken.'
word_list [u'hey', u'my', u'spacebar', u'is', u'broken', u'']
```

My work around is to use 
`re.split(r'[\W_]+', unicode(phrase.strip('.'), 'utf-8').lower(), flags=re.U)`
 but I wanted to know is there was a way to solve it within the regex expression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex split without empty string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840851/python-regex-split-without-empty-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\W` selects non-word characters. Since `.` is a non-word character, the string is split on it. Since there is nothing after the period, you get an empty string. If you want to avoid this, you'll need to either strip the separator characters of the ends of the string

```
phrase = re.sub(r'^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$', '', phrase)
```

or filter the resulting array to remove empty strings.

```
word_list = [word for word in word_list if word]
```

Alternatively, you can get the words by matching them directly rather than splitting:

```
words = re.findall(r'[^\W_]+', phrase)
```

Comment: using the `findall` method is much cleaner than trying to use sub. and it returns a list by default, which is what I wanted and mistakenly thought I needed `split` to get back.