# Python regex split multiple matches

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm trying to split strings containing sequences of 2 different characters into groups. If we assume the characters are `a` and `b`, the plain text rules for grouping are:

- groups consist of 0+ `a`'s followed by 1+ `b`'s
- all following `a`'s are included in the next group, unless we're at the end of the word.

For example: after processing `tests` the goal is to break into groups like `expected`.

```
tests = ['abab',
    'ababab',
    'aabab',
    'aababa',
    'aba',
    'baba']

expected = [['ab','ab'],
    ['ab','ab','ab'],
    ['aab','ab'],
    ['aab','aba'],
    ['aba'],
    ['b','aba']]
```

The closest I've gotten is the below:

```
import re

# filter() returns iterator not list in Python 3 
def testing(s):
    return list(filter(None, re.compile('(a*b+a*(?=$))').split(s)))

output = [testing(s) for s in tests]

output

[['ab', 'ab'], ['abab', 'ab'], ['aab', 'ab'], ['aab', 'aba'], ['aba']]
```

Which does well on groups of 1-2 but not for groups larger than that, which means my regex needs improvement. Should I rethink the approach? I could probably do something brute force with for loops but was hoping for something more elegant.

N.B.: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840851/python-regex-split-without-empty-string) leads me to believe that .split() may not be the way to go here, but I've gotten the best results with it so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're on the right track. However, your regex has more bugs than you think. Your test cases do not cover all possible scenarios, and so you don't realise this.

Since you have a couple of special cases, you should treat them separately. For example, the last input is a special case because it matches `aba`. Similarly, list the others separately and join them with `|`. You can also use `re.findall`, it's cleaner.

```
tests = ['abab',
        'ababab',
        'aabab',
        'aababa',
        'aba',
        'baba']

def testing(s):
    return re.findall('(?:a*b+a+$)|(?:a*b+)|(?:b+a+)', s)

output = [testing(s) for s in tests]   
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[['ab', 'ab'], ['ab', 'ab', 'ab'], ['aab', 'ab'], ['aab', 'aba'], ['aba'], ['b', 'aba']]
```

Comment: This answer works for my original test cases and the explanation is very useful, but it doesn't work for cases in which we have a string starting with 0 `a`'s. 

    testing('bab')

yields `['bab']` instead of `['b', 'ab']`

I edited the test cases to reflect the prose cases.

Comment: @Eric My bad, I didn't see that requirement. I've fixed that, and it works now. I still think this regex is better than the one you accepted because it handles all special cases explicitly. Do reconsider which you use.

Comment: I appreciate your explanations and matching your answer format to that of my question.

Comment: @Eric Cheers, glad to have helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

This gives me correct results for the test data:

```
tests = ['abab',
'ababab',
'aabab',
'aababa',
'aba',
'baba',
'abba']

for s in tests:
    r = re.findall("(?:a*b+a*$)|(?:a*b+)",s)
    print(r)
```

Results:

```
['ab', 'ab']
['ab', 'ab', 'ab']
['aab', 'ab']
['aab', 'aba']
['aba']
['b', 'aba']
['abba']
```