# Python split with some delimiters and dont get empty elements in the list

Tags: python

I tried that code to get the number of a string like that: "some_name[number]"

```
name= "asdf[105]"
re.split("\[|\]", name)
```

And i get that list.

```
['asdf', '105', '']
```

Anyone know how can i get a list without the empty element?
Is there a way to get that without deleting de empty elements of the list after?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex split without empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840851/python-regex-split-without-empty-string)

Comment: Hey, thank you and sorry for duplicate a question. I think the easy solution would be to get rid of empty elements..   
`name = filter(None,name)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension.

```
l = ['asdf', '105', '']
l = [element for element in l if element != '']
```

So your code would be

```
import re

name = "asdf[105]"
l = [element for element in re.split("\[|\]", name) if element != '']
print(l)  # ['asdf', '105']
```

Or, if you'd like to keep a list with the empty elements,

```
import re

name = "asdf[105]"
list_with_empty_elements = re.split("\[|\]", name)
list_without_empty_elements = [element for element in list_with_empty_elements if element != '']
```

Comment: He said "without deleting de empty elements of the list after"

Comment: Technically this isn't _deleting_ elements.

Comment: But you're getting rid of empty elements

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. right, edited to add an example that keeps both lists.